# How to filter wireshark output data to only view ttyUSB0 data?

Tags: usb, wireshark, ttyusb

I'm Using Wireshark on Ubuntu 18.04 to monitor my `ttyUSB0` USB port output as I'm developing something that requires that. On the website, I found how to get it to sniff USB ports but the output is really huge that I can't see the data I'm interested in.

I always set it to usbmonX, x is the number of the bus number that my device is connected to. I get that number using lsusb command, but it shows a huge amount of traffic that has nothing to do with my device.

I managed to get some filters to work. like `usb.idProduct` and `usb.idVendor` but they don't really view the packets when I send them to the device on the USB. These filters only the signal that the device sends once it connected to the PC.

Is there a filter that can output all the traffic of `ttyUSB0` port?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Before setting a filter, you can tell it to listen on only one device.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor well, how?

Comment: When you first start a trace, it asks.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get it to work by combining two filters. You have to get the vendor id or the product id and its easy. Just use `usbview`. After getting any id of them, apply this filter `usb.idVendor == Your-device-vendor-ID`.

This filter won't get you all the traffic of the filter so you have to add another filter. Get the destination address that the PC uses to communicate with your device, It's usually something like `2.1.0`. Then apply this filter `usb.idVendor == The-vendor-ID and usb.adrr == "The address you got"`. Don't forget to wrap the address inside `" "`.

Comment: First, *how* do we find the destination address from something like `lsusb` when other guides I've seen treat it as a Wireshark-internal thing unrelated to output from other tools? Second, why does a filter that looks like it should *narrow* the match (`x and y`) actually widen it?