# I want to view data leaving via /dev/ttyUSB0

Tags: linux, tty

I need confidence that the data my Raspberry Pi is telling me it's sending to an external device via USB is actually leaving the Pi.  I was hoping there would be some way of printing the serial data to the screen or a file.

I've looked at 'cat' but don't think this can do what I need

How do I  view data leaving via /dev/ttyUSB0?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are these helpful? [How can I monitor serial port traffic?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12359/108618) [How to filter wireshark output data to only view ttyUSB0 data?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/496497/108618)